# How can i work with templates in Python-pptx

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-pptx

I know this module is not very popular but if you know the answer then please help me out with it.

My code is:

```
from pptx import Presentation
prs = Presentation('template.pptx')
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layout[0]
# print(len(prs.slide_layout))
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
title = slide.shapes.title
subtitle = slide.placeholders[1]

title.text = "Python 3.6 - Turtle Race"
subtitle.text = "Data Analytics&Visualization with random generated data"

prs.save("out.pptx")
```

An error I have got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!_!Piton/turtleRace/presentationMaker.py", line 8, in <module>
    prs = Presentation('template.pptx')
  File "D:\!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!_!Piton\turtleRace\venv\lib\site-packages\pptx\api.py", line 28, in Presentation
    presentation_part = Package.open(pptx).main_document_part
  File "D:\!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!_!Piton\turtleRace\venv\lib\site-packages\pptx\opc\package.py", line 103, in main_document_part
    return self.part_related_by(RT.OFFICE_DOCUMENT)
  File "D:\!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!_!Piton\turtleRace\venv\lib\site-packages\pptx\opc\package.py", line 136, in part_related_by
    return self.rels.part_with_reltype(reltype)
  File "D:\!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!_!Piton\turtleRace\venv\lib\site-packages\pptx\opc\package.py", line 439, in part_with_reltype
    rel = self._get_rel_of_type(reltype)
  File "D:\!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!_!Piton\turtleRace\venv\lib\site-packages\pptx\opc\package.py", line 491, in _get_rel_of_type
    raise KeyError(tmpl % reltype)
KeyError: "no relationship of type 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument' in collection"
```

A picture of my project interpreter:
[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrljo.png)

So why I have got this error?

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue about the type when you save the file as Strict Open XML Presentation. Try the standard Presentation document.

You can get more informations about relations inside the file using [opc-diag](https://github.com/python-openxml/opc-diag):

You can resolve error [Here](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/204)

Trying to fix a old file:

Extract

`unzip <FILE> -d old-file`

Repackage it into a new fresh file

```
opc repackage bad-file new-file.docx
```

diff of relationships

```
opc diff-item test.docx test-ok.docx .rels
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I just read it after I found the solution :'D!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution!!!

Before I saved the file(called template) as Strict Open XML Presentation(.pptx) 
                                 and not as PowerPoint Presentation(.pptx)

It's now opening the file but now I have another error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!_!Piton/turtleRace/presentationMaker.py", line 9, in <module>
    title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layout[0]
AttributeError: 'Presentation' object has no attribute 'slide_layout'
```

Everything is the same just the saving method in PowerPoint has changed.